# trying to run ping from GKE pod, error: ping: socket: Operation not permitted

Tags: kubernetes, networking, google-kubernetes-engine, ping

Trying to run a one-off container based on [this image](https://github.com/arunvelsriram/utils/blob/master/Dockerfile) with command: `kubectl run --rm utils -it --image arunvelsriram/utils bash` which works but when I try to ping I get:

```
ping google.com
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

Some solutions to this mention to try running:

`setcap cap_net_raw=ep $(which ping)`

but then I get error: `bash: setcap: command not found` If I try installing it I keep running into this error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Is there any image that allows me to ping from kubernetes pod in GKE?

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this and it worked fine, see if you have any additional restrictions on your cluster, that it drops linux capabilities

```
kubectl run --rm utils -it --image arunvelsriram/utils bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
utils@utils:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (209.85.202.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dg-in-f102.1e100.net (209.85.202.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=101 time=1.45 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.457/1.457/1.457/0.000 ms
utils@utils:~$
```

Comment: hey Ali, for a kubernetes beginner can you elaborate a bit further thanks

Comment: as can see its running fine on my Kubernetes cluster, then I am assuming that in your Kubernetes cluster there might be some constraints, that restrict running pods to run in privileged mode, or run in readOnly mode, you can try running id command and see with which user its running and then run touch a.txt to confirm if you are able to write files or not

Comment: it's running on root user and I'm able to create a file and write to it for example